# How to convert a string array to a cell array of string?

Tags: matlab

I have a string array:

```
array = ['123';'abc';'uvw'];
```

I want convert it to a cell array of string:

```
cellArr = {'123';'abc';'uvw'};
```

There are two ways in my idea: allocating a cell array then using a for loop or

```
cellArr = arrayfun(@(x) array(x,:),1:size(array,1),'UniformOutput',false)';
```

But I'm not sure if there is a build-in function do this more effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cellstr()`. Simply `cellstr (array)` should work. It also works in Octave.

Alternatively, a more complicated but fun way to look into is

`mat2cell (array, ones (size (array, 1), 1), size (array, 2))`

which in Octave can be

`mat2cell (array, ones (rows (array), 1), columns (array))`